# How to show calender date based on users location using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Actually i want to show the user's local date in the calender using jquery datepicker. By default, the calender is showing the Brisbane, Australia time. But i want to show the date based on the user comes from the location. Like if the user is coming from US, Europe, UAE, UK etc then i have to show these locations. Is there any solution available in Javascript? Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: what calendar you are using, as far i know it will be default behavior of JavaScript to show date according to the client machine

Comment: Use moment.js. `moment.utc()` will set moment to do everything in utc then when you are going to display anywhere... use localized format.

Comment: Saqueib, i am using the jquery datepicker

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j4mwomgh/1/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Date().toLocaleString()
```

But this will only work if your date is stored in ISO or UTC format or you date is GMT.
If not then you will have to convert it into unix-time and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by combining your code with php. Here get timezone from user and save that in one variable. After then code as below:

```
$UtimeZ = usertimezone;
date_default_timezone_set('$UtimeZ');
$UserDateTime = date('Y-m-d H-i-s');
```

Now show that date in calender using javascript.